# Is http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring wrong?

Tags: jquery

I am learning how to create my own plugin, and am strongly following the article at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring.  The particular portion I have a question relates to adding events to elements as shown on http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Events.

A live demo is included at http://jsfiddle.net/bhcEk/.  It is basically the same, except binds the click() event instead of the resize event, and applies the plugin to several elements of a given class, except one element.

Clicking the element results in (3) alerts.  As seen by the below script taken from the article, the event is added within the each() loop, so this is to be expected.

EDIT. Yicks!  It is worse than I though.  It adds it the the windows element, so all elements when clicked will trigger it.  Maybe just return $(window) with $(this)?

It seems to me the article is wrong and it should be added (and removed under destroy) just once.  The people who wrote the article, however, are much more experienced than me, and it might be foolish for me to doubt them.  Is the article wrong, or is it me?

```
init : function( options ) {
 return this.each(function(){
  $(window).bind('resize.tooltip', methods.reposition);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The article appears to be fine.  In your Fiddle the desired behaviour differs so the context in which it is applied will have to too - you are correct in assuming `this` is now more appropriate.

Sounds like you have been staring at the screen too long ;-)

EDIT (in response to comment):

Pretty much everything in jQuery is encapsulated to avoid conflicts.  At the risk of confusing matters, "binding" is like a fifo stack (first-in, first-out array).

In the example in the article you're applying the behaviour to multiple individual elements which aren't aware of each other (and have no need to be), they just share a common event - when the function in the example is bound to an event it is actually adding multiple handlers to the window's event stack.

possibly over simplified pseudo:

```
window.events [ // array [ event, namespace, function ]
  [ 'resize', 'tooltip', function(){ /* specific to element 1 */ }],
  [ 'resize', 'tooltip', function(){ /* specific to element 2 */ }],
  [ 'resize', 'tooltip', function(){ /* specific to element 3 */ }]
]
```

when the window resize event is triggered, it runs each function in the stack in sequence.  the "tooltip" namespace doesn't refer to a specific event handler, it's a name for a group of similar handlers which are ultimately independent of one another.

I hope that makes sense, it's difficult to express it in words.

Comment: Thanks Emissary.  Agree that the article works for its particular case, but should I ever create a plugin that way where the same event can be bond to "window" multiple times?  Shouldn't either this always be used if in the loop, and only bind to window once out of the loop?

Comment: I think you are confusing the namespace with a single reference.  I'll amend my answer - hold on.

Comment: Thanks again Emissary,  I kind of get what you are saying.  Still struggling on the section where you show [ 'resize', 'tooltip', function(){ /* specific to element 1 */ }], then for element 2 and 3.  Where is it being assigned to one specific element or another?   All I see is $(window).bind('resize.tooltip', methods.reposition), and it doesn't seem to specify one element or another.  Thanks!

Comment: The tooltip plugin is kind of abstract and adopts the scope of whatever jQuery object it is applied to.  So each incarnation of the function is tailored - so to speak - to each element.  Any reference to an element in the window.resize event "stack" is implicit and handled by jQuery itself.  I hope my terminology is okay - I'm testing myself here too.

Comment: Each incarnation of the function is tailored to each element?  I created http://jsfiddle.net/bhcEk/1/ to see whether "this" is different between each element, and it is not.  So I still don't understand why one would have multiple $(window).bind('resize.tooltip', methods.reposition).

Comment: `this` is just a keyword that refer to the current object in the scope , the element - each element is different.  Alas, it sounds like i'm confusing matters.  Hopefully someone else can jump in? bounty?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between your plugin instance and the article's is that there is only one `$(window)` and one `resize()` simultaneous event of that element.  The article then uses this as the basis for when the `reposition()` method fires.

In your instance, there are 3 `.tooltip` elements.  By returning `.each()` of the 3 elements and calling back a `click` function that binds to the `$(window)`, then it actually fires the event for each element.

Instead of binding to the `$(window)`, bind to `$(this)` (which is only binding the event to the current target (the clicked `.tooltip`).

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/T6H84/) of your original with that one change I mentioned.